# Electron.js app notarizing fails with Your Apple ID account is attached to other providers

Tags: macos, electron, codesign, notarize

I am trying to notarize my electron.js app on Mac.
Code signing is successful, and it then sends the `.app` file to the server for notarization, but then the process fails with error (added error below).

From searching online, I found that this issue is related to `ascProvider` field.
I took the `ProviderShortName` with command `xcrun altool --list-providers -u <APPLEID> -p <APP_PASSWORD>` and added it to `ascProvider`, it should have fixed the error, but notarization process still fails the same.

Are the any other possibilities to fix this error ?

**Error i am getting from notarization**

```
Your Apple ID account is attached to other providers. You will need to specify which provider you intend to submit content to. Please contact us if you have questions or need help. (1627)
2021-03-01 15:00:17.378 altool[48448:1515802] *** Error: Unable to notarize app.
2021-03-01 15:00:17.378 altool[48448:1515802] *** Error: code 1627 (Your Apple ID account is attached to other providers. You will need to specify which provider you intend to submit content to. Please contact us if you have questions or need help. (1627))
```

My `notarizing.js` is like this

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { notarize } = require('electron-notarize');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

exports.default = async function notarizing(params) {
  const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = params;
  if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
    return;
  }

  console.log('afterSign hook triggered', params.targets);
  // Same appId in electron-builder.  
  let appId = 'my.app.com'
  let appPath = path.join(params.appOutDir, `${params.packager.appInfo.productFilename}.app`);
  if (!fs.existsSync(appPath)) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot find application at: ${appPath}`);
  }

  console.log(`Notarizing ${appId} found at ${appPath}`);

  try {
    await notarize({
      appBundleId: appId,
      appPath: appPath,
      appleId: process.env.APPLEID,
      appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLEIDPASS,
      ascProvider: process.env.APPLEPROVIDER,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  console.log(`Done notarizing ${appId}`);
};
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I came here because of a similar error message. I had tried to use my main Apple ID password in the notarizer's `.env` settings. That would lead to an auth error. What worked was to generate an application-specific password in https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage.